# How can we reinterpret a double or float as NSUInteger to create hash?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, reinterpret-cast

This is my isEqual and hash custom operator

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object;
{
    BGSearchParameter * theOther = (BGSearchParameter *)object;

    BOOL isTheOtherEqual;
    isTheOtherEqual = isTheOtherEqual && [self.Location isEqual:theOther.Location];
    isTheOtherEqual = isTheOtherEqual && [self.keyword isEqual:theOther.keyword];
    isTheOtherEqual = isTheOtherEqual && (self.Distance == theOther.Distance);
    isTheOtherEqual = isTheOtherEqual && (self.SortByWhat == theOther.SortByWhat);
    isTheOtherEqual = isTheOtherEqual && (self.startFrom == theOther.startFrom);
    isTheOtherEqual = isTheOtherEqual && (self.numberOfIDstoGrab == theOther.numberOfIDstoGrab);

    return isTheOtherEqual;
}
- (NSUInteger)hash
{
    NSUInteger returnValue=0;
    returnValue ^= self.Location.hash;
    returnValue ^= self.keyword.hash;

    return returnValue;
}
```

That one does the job. However, say I want to incorporate the distance and the startfrom into the hash.

I guess I will simply add:

```
returnValue ^= self.Distance;
```

It's an error because it's not compatible.

So what should I do instead?

Comment: Note that there's a subtle bug with the `isTheOtherEqual` not being initialized to `YES`.

Comment: It should be noted that, as a floating-point number is generally not exact, the hash value will be useless in the same situations where comparing with `==` will be useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up turning the number into NSNumber and got the hash:

```
   returnValue ^= @(self.Distance).hash;
   returnValue ^= @(self.SortByWhat).hash;
   returnValue ^= @(self.startFrom).hash;
   returnValue ^= @(self.numberOfIDstoGrab).hash;
```

Martin answer is good. However, the result should be the same anyway and I don't want to implement another complicated function.

Comment: You can do that of course. But you should be aware that you allocate/init and release a `NSNumber` object each time, so it is more overhead.

Comment: I know. But it's still O(1); Your answer is still selected. It's just too complicated to implement.

Comment: Your solution really demonstrates the elegance of the new @() notation. As you suggest, focus first on simple, readable, robust, elegant code. Then focus on performance where it is most needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is what `CFNumber`/`NSNumber` use as hash value for `float` and `double` values, see for example [ForFoundationOnly.h](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635.21/ForFoundationOnly.h) in Mac OS X 10.7.5 Source.

```
#define HASHFACTOR 2654435761U

CF_INLINE CFHashCode _CFHashDouble(double d) {
    double dInt;
    if (d < 0) d = -d;
    dInt = floor(d+0.5);
    CFHashCode integralHash = HASHFACTOR * (CFHashCode)fmod(dInt, (double)ULONG_MAX);
    return (CFHashCode)(integralHash + (CFHashCode)((d - dInt) * ULONG_MAX));
}
```

`CFHashCode` is defined as

```
typedef unsigned long CFHashCode;
```

Comment: the function start with _. Can we useit? Is that a private function?

Comment: @HaryantoCiu: The function is used by the CoreFoundation framework internally. If you want to use it, I would recommend to implement it yourself with a different name.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
static NSUInteger doubleHash(float value) {
    return *(NSUInteger *)&value;//gets bits
}
```

Notice the conversion to float. It decreases precision, but sizeof(float)==sizeof(NSUInteger).